# How to select a html tag by its style? With Beautifulsoup and Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

So i might have a tag such as:

```
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:5.5pt;margin-bottom:.6pt;
margin-left:2.05pt'>bla bla bla</p>
```

I want to be able to select by the `margin-right:5pt`

Any tag that has this style I would like to extract please.

At the moment I have this code but it isn't extracting anything:

```
p_tag = name.find_all('p', {'style':'margin-right:5.5pt'})
print(p_tag)
```

Here is more of the html code that I have:

```
<h1 style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:1.75pt;margin-bottom:.25pt;margin- 
left:-.25pt'>Some header tag </h1>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin:0cm;margin-bottom:.0001pt;text-indent:0cm;
line-height:107%'> </p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:5.5pt;margin-bottom:.6pt;
margin-left:2.05pt'>Some name<i>some place they work</i> 
</p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:0cm;margin-bottom:1.2pt;
margin-left:0cm;text-indent:0cm;line-height:107%'>  </p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:5.5pt;margin-bottom:.6pt;
margin-left:2.05pt'>short description about the person</p>

<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:5.5pt;margin-bottom:4.5pt;
margin-left:2.05pt'>some more info...</p>
```

Can I merge all the p tags with the specific margin until the `<h1>` tag appears again?

Comment: Can you post the HTML?

Comment: I'm afraid not as it is sensitive material, but i can post a simplified version if that helps?

Answer (score 2):

You're using an exact match, but you intend a partial match. Try this instead:

```
p_tag = name.find_all('p', {'style': lambda s: 'margin-right:5.5pt' in s})
print(p_tag)
```

Answer (score 1):

BeautifulSoup has quite good support for [CSS selectors using the `.select` method](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors). CSS has some fairly powerful ways of [selecting elements based on attribute values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

In your case you want to select elements that have the attribute `style` **containing** `margin-right:5.5pt` which can be written as the CSS selector `[style*='margin-right:5.5pt']`.

Combining this knowledge a solution for your question would be:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:5.5pt;margin-bottom:.6pt;margin-left:2.05pt'>test1</p>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0cm;margin-bottom:.6pt;margin-left:2.05pt'>test2</p>
<p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:5pt;margin-bottom:.6pt;margin-left:2.05pt'>test3</p>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
[el.extract() for el in soup.select("[style*='margin-right:5.5pt']")]
print(soup.prettify())
```

Which would give the following output:

```
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-top:0cm;margin-bottom:.6pt;margin-left:2.05pt">test2</p>
<p class="MsoNormal" style="margin-top:0cm;margin-right:5pt;margin-bottom:.6pt;margin-left:2.05pt">test3</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use if statement

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = ''' <p class=MsoNormal style='margin-top:0cm;margin-right:5.5pt;margin-bottom:.6pt;margin-left:2.05pt'>bla bla bla</p>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
p_tag = soup.find_all('p')[0]['style']
if 'margin-right:5.5pt' in p_tag:
    print(p_tag)
else:
    print('Not found')
```

Output:

```
margin-top:0cm;margin-right:5.5pt;margin-bottom:.6pt;margin-left:2.05pt
```